# could you please explain why the names(df) not working within dfplyr::arrange()

Tags: r, dplyr

could you please explain why the names(df) not working within dfplyr::arrange(), is there a way to make it work

```r
nam <- names(mtcars)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% arrange(nam)
```

Comment: no i wanted to sort the dataframe in the order of the variables in the dataframe. the answer provided by @akrun works with across, but i wanted to know the same is not required for select()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With more than one column, we may use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    arrange(across(all_of(nam)))
```

There is a difference in the behavior of variadic input (`...`) between `select` and functions like `mutate/arrange/summarise`

#select

> ...  - **tidy-select** -  One or more unquoted expressions separated by commas. Variable names can be used as if they were positions in the data frame, so expressions like x:y can be used to select a range of variables.

#arrange (similar with mutate/filter)

> ... - **data-masking**- Variables, or functions of variables. Use desc() to sort a variable in descending order.

Comment: thank you @akrun, could you please let me know the reason for this why it is not working  without across whereas the same works in select like select(nam)

Comment: @jkatam If you check the docs, it says `# Use `across()` or `pick()` to select columns with tidy-select` in `arrange` (as it is a [colwise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html) operation)